# Expressing division as subtraction/addition

Tags: arithmetic

Can one express division as subtraction/addition like one can express multiplication as addition?

Like $2 \times 3 = 2+2+2$, can it also be done on division, like saying "$3$ = the number of times $2$ was subtracted from $6$?"

Comment: You only seem to be considering a specific case where a number is perfectly divisible by another. Are you interested in situations such as $\frac{7}{3}$ ?

Comment: @Bruce yes,im only talking about numbers that are perfectly divisible.

Answer (score 1):

Division can just be represented as subtraction or addition.

For example:

$6 \div 3$ can be represented as $6-(3+3)$ or $6-3-3$

Since $6-(3+3)= 0$, we know that 3 can be fitted into 6 two times $3+3$, two 3s.

We basically subtract the dividend by the divisor until it reaches 0. (or less than the divisor, then the remaining is the remainder)